# How can I bind WPF TextBlock text to different properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Based on MVVM Pattern, I have these two properties in my MODEL :

```
public string DestinationCode
```

AND

```
public enum OperatingMode
{
    Unknown,
    [Description("Zzz")]
    Asleep,
    Standby,
    [Description("WKU")]
    WakeUp
}
```

Senario : I want the TextBlock Text shows :

-DestinationCode

-"Zzz" if the OperatingMode is 'asleep'

-"WKU" if the OperatingMode is 'WakeUp'

Comment: If you bind your `TextBox` to the `DestinationCode`, the logic should be in `DestinationCode` with some binding and `INotifyPropertychange`.

Comment: @Bob How can I do this logic in `DestinationCode` ? can i have more explanations plz

Answer (score 2):

For your property `DestinationCode`, the binding need `INotifyPropertychange` to alert his change. For ex, this is your class:

```
public class Your_Class: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _destinationCode;
    public string DestinationCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _destinationCode;
        }
        set
        {
            _destinationCode = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DestinationCode");
        }
    }

    private OperatingMode _my_Enum;
    public OperatingMode My_Enum
    {
        get
        {
            return _my_Enum;
        }
        set
        {
            _my_Enum = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("My_Enum");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

To binding your enum `My_Enum`, you must first create a converter to get the description of enum. Something likes :

```
public class EnumDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private string GetEnumDescription(Enum enumObj)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = enumObj.GetType().GetField(enumObj.ToString());

        object[] attribArray = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        if (attribArray.Length == 0)
        {
            return enumObj.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            DescriptionAttribute attrib = attribArray[0] as DescriptionAttribute;
            return attrib.Description;
        }
    }

    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Enum myEnum = (Enum)value;
        string description = GetEnumDescription(myEnum);
        return description;
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Next, your `TextBox` should use this converter

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding My_Enum, Converter={StaticResource EnumDescriptionConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: You should manage null values for     GetEnumDescription    and     IValueConverter.Convert    .

Comment: @maulikkansara where I should check null ? Enum isn't nullable

Comment: "object value" can be null or empty as it is being passed form string property.

Comment: In the question of OP, he didn't remarque his property in class being a string or Enum. So, in my answer, I suppose it's an enum in the Your_Class. So, it can't be null.

Comment: You are using "My_Enum" but as in question, the guy is using string property "DestinationCode".

Comment: He said :  I have these two properties in my MODEL, one a string and one a enum or string

Comment: yes yes. question is not clear. let it be some homework for the guy. by the way your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the text should show the DestinationCode unless the OperatingMode is set to a value that has a description:

A solution would be to use a multi binding and a multi value converter.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Width="200"
        Height="150"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:DestinationAndOperationModeToDescriptionConverter x:Key="DestinationAndOperationModeToDescription" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DestinationAndOperationModeToDescription}">
                    <Binding Path="DestinationCode" />
                    <Binding Path="OperatingMode" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The multivalue converter could look like this:

```
public class DestinationAndOperationModeToDescriptionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length < 2)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        string destinationCode;
        OperatingMode operatingMode;
        if (values[0] is string && values[1] is OperatingMode)
        {
            destinationCode = values[0] as string;
            operatingMode = (OperatingMode)values[1];
        }
        else if (values[1] is string && values[0] is OperatingMode)
        {
            destinationCode = values[1] as string;
            operatingMode = (OperatingMode)values[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        var descriptionAttribute =
            typeof(OperatingMode)
                .GetField(operatingMode.ToString())
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(descriptionAttribute?.Description))
        {
            return destinationCode;
        }

        return descriptionAttribute.Description;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The ViewModel would look like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string destinationCode;
    private OperatingMode operatingMode;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string DestinationCode
    {
        get
        {
            return destinationCode;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.destinationCode == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            destinationCode = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public OperatingMode OperatingMode
    {
        get
        {
            return operatingMode;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.operatingMode == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            operatingMode = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```